# Accessing Azure Pipeline variable in Python script

Tags: python, variables, azure-pipelines

I am facing problem during accessing Pipeline variable inside inline python script.

In prefious task CyberArk retrieves two passwords from vault and saves it into pipeline variables

`PAS.Account1_ad_com` and
`PAS.Account2_ad_com`

I have a list of accounts earlies but it looks like this
`Account1@ad.com,Account2@ad.com`

So in my Python Task:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import json
      import os
      vars = ${{ parameters.vars }}
      alist = str("$(alist)")
      pyvars = json.loads(vars .replace("'", '"'))
      pyalist = alist .split(",")
      yy = "$(PAS.Account1_ad_com)"
      print(str(yy))
      for index, account in enumerate(pyalist):
        account_tmp="PAS." + account.replace(".", "_").replace("@", "_")
        account_pass_tmp = "$(PAS." + account.replace(".", "_").replace("@", "_") + ")"
        print(str(account_pass_tmp))
        pyvars[index][account_tmp] = str(f"{account_pass_tmp}")
      print(pyvars)
```

In this code you can see variable `yy` made for tests and print after this and this works. It shows *** in pipeline so it means it returns password correctly.

But i can't hardcode account name because its filled by user during start of the pipeline (in parameters), so i am creating this variable inside `account_pass_tmp` and on the first look you can see that

```
yy = "$(PAS.Account1_ad_com)"
      print(str(yy))
```

and

```
account_pass_tmp = "$(PAS." + account.replace(".", "_").replace("@", "_") + ")"
        print(str(account_pass_tmp))
```

does not differ but the second one returns two strings `$(PAS.Account1_ad_com)` and `$(PAS.Account2_ad_com)`instead two times ***

Why it does not work as the hardcoded `yy` variable?